# Spark create dataset using encoder where row is array type

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am unable to figure out, the correct implementation for encoder to create Dataset from below RDD?

e.g.

```
JavaRDD<Integer[]>rdd= sparkContext.parallelize(
                Arrays.asList(new Integer[][]{new Integer[]{1,2},
                new Integer[]{3,4}
                ,new Integer[]{6,7}}));
```

Below implementation fails-

```
DataSet<Integer> ds = sqlContext.createDataset(rdd.rdd(),Encoders.bean(Integer[].class));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
>     at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)

How to create encode for array type? Thanks!

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this? I encountered the same problem when trying to use long[] type in custom aggregator.

Answer (score -1):

Please try converting it first to DataFrame and then to Dataset

```
Dataset<Integer[]> dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, Integer[].class);
Dataset<Integer[]> ds = dataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(Integer[].class));
```

Comment: For `spark.createDataset(strings, Encoders.bean(String[].class))` I am getting ```java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
 at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:87)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)```

I am trying to create a Dataset from `List<String[]>`